# How to resend a request after receiving 503 response

Tags: ruby

I'm sending GET requests to a server. If I get a 503 response, I want to send the request again.

Here is my code:

```
status_code = 503
while status_code == 503
    puts status_code
    sleep 0.1 + rand
    page, status_code = send_request(query_url(query, page_number))
    puts status_code
end
```

Watching the console, I see that even if two 503s are logged in a row, the loop is exited.

I've tried the inverse:

```
status_code = 200
until status_code == 200
    puts status_code
    sleep 0.1 + rand
    page, status_code = send_request(query_url(query, page_number))
    puts status_code
end
```

But now the loop never exits. I've obviously misunderstood something completely basic. How do I write the loop so that it continues until the code is not 503/until it's 200?

Comment: The later code should never execute the contents of the loop. `status_code` gets set to 200, then then the condition is immediately checked and the loop is skipped as a result. Is that not what happens for you?

Comment: The first example looks right. Are you sure `send_request` is returning an integer as the second element of the array? Could it be the string `"503"`?

Comment: Adding 'to_i' to the return value did the trick!

Comment: @mlovic: why not post as an answer?

Comment: @orde: Just did, thanks!

Comment: Using `sleep 0.1 + rand` as your delay for a 503 error is not being a very good net-citizen, and, if you're pounding on a server that's already being overwhelmed, it won't do you any good, you'll just add to the problem, and possibly get marked as having contributed to the problem and get banned. If it's a server that's offline you'll just waste your CPU and network. Instead set a long sleep value, without any randomization, or just exit and rerun the job later.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop in the first example looks right. `send_request` is probably returning the string `"503"`, instead of an integer, so the comparison with the integer `503` returns false. Try either comparing with a string

```
status_code == "503"
# => true
```

or coercing the return value of send_request into an integer

```
status_code.to_i == 501
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks @Suever. My original comment solved the problem, so I posted it as an answer. I've edited the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the values you check are different types, and because of this your `while` is exited.

Check the type of the object:

```
puts status_code.class
sleep 0.1 + rand
page, status_code = send_request(query_url(query, page_number))
puts status_code.class
```

Comment: response_code is the second return value in my send_request method